# Discord.py not unpinning own bot's messages

Tags: discord, discord.py

My test code is

```
@bot.command(name='test')
async def test(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send('test')
    channel = ctx.channel
    message = await channel.fetch_message(message.id)
    await message.pin()
    await message.unpin()
```

The bot pins the message but it won't unpin it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested the code, it works fine for me.

**NOTE-** Discord only shows a message that someone has pinned the message, but discord does not show if someone has unpinned it, you need to check it in the pinned messages.

Comment: I tested it now and it works too. I don't know why it didn't work last time but before I posted the question the code in channel was `channel = message.channel`.

Comment: something you should be aware of is that while you are calling `await message.pin()`, that will return upon you successfully sending that command to discord.  It _DOES NOT_ ensure that the command completes.  So you could be hitting a race condition where the discord server receives the `unpin()` prior to the pin.

Answer (score -1):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged successfully!')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send('test')
    await message.pin()
    await message.unpin()

bot.run('BOT_TOKEN_HERE')
```